# Active model Serializers does not work when i try to return a hash of multiple models via Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I am working on Rails 5 api only app.

So this is my model serializer

```
class MovieSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id ,:name,:release_year,:story,:in_theater,:poster,:score,:user_count

  belongs_to :age_rating
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :category , through: :movie_category

end

class CelebritySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name

  has_many :movie_celebrity

end

class MovieCelebritySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,:vacancy,:title

  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :celebrity

end
```

This is my controller

```
class Api::V1::MoviesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /v1/movies/:id
  def show

    movie = Movie.find_by(id: params[:id])
    casts = MovieCelebrity.where(movie_id: params[:id],vacancy: "cast")
    directors = MovieCelebrity.where(movie_id: params[:id],vacancy: "director")

    render :json => {:movie => movie, :casts => casts , :directors => directors}
  end

end
```

So this is what i got when i made a request

```
{
  "movie": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "0 The Doors of Perception",
    "release_year": 2007,
    "story": "Non doloribus qui et eum impedit. Rerum mollitia debitis sit nesciunt. Vero autem quae sit aliquid rerum ex fugit. Eligendi assumenda et eos. Blanditiis hic ut. Commodi quo sunt voluptatem quasi.",
    "in_theater": false,
    "age_rating_id": 2,
    "company_id": 5,
    "created_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:26.213Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:26.213Z",
    "release_date": "2016-01-18",
    "poster": "'http://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/15399e7a7b11a8c2ef28511107c90c6f.jpg',",
    "score": 0,
    "user_count": 6950
  },
  "casts": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "vacancy": "cast",
      "title": "Pro x",
      "movie_id": 1,
      "celebrity_id": 56,
      "created_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:28.001Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:28.001Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "vacancy": "cast",
      "title": "Magneto",
      "movie_id": 1,
      "celebrity_id": 23,
      "created_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:28.006Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:28.006Z"
    }
  ],
  "directors": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "vacancy": "director",
      "title": "",
      "movie_id": 1,
      "celebrity_id": 17,
      "created_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:27.993Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-12T12:45:27.993Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems like Active model serializer did not work.
Because if i only return one object it worked fine like this.

```
def show

    movie = Movie.find_by(id: params[:id])
    casts = MovieCelebrity.where(movie_id: params[:id],vacancy: "cast")
    directors = MovieCelebrity.where(movie_id: params[:id],vacancy: "director")

    #render :json => { :movie => movie, :casts => casts , :directors => directors }
    render :json => movie

end



{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "0 The Doors of Perception",
  "release_year": 2007,
  "story": "Non doloribus qui et eum impedit. Rerum mollitia debitis sit nesciunt. Vero autem quae sit aliquid rerum ex fugit. Eligendi assumenda et eos. Blanditiis hic ut. Commodi quo sunt voluptatem quasi.",
  "in_theater": false,
  "poster": "'http://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/15399e7a7b11a8c2ef28511107c90c6f.jpg',",
  "score": 0,
  "user_count": 6950,
  "age_rating": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "PG"
  },
  "company": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Gislason, Jacobs and Graham"
  },
  "category": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Biography"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Mystery"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i fixed this and make the Active model serializer works fine with multiple models hash object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [explicit serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md#explicit-serializer) like this:

```
render json: {movie: movie, casts: casts , directors: directors}, serializer: MovieCastDirectorSerializer
```

Because AMS doesn't know which serializer needed for your plain ruby object that you construct here.

**Update:**
But even if you do so, AMS still will be unable to serialize that as it will be not ActiveModel object. [There is an example](https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/active-model-serializers) of how to deal with that. But for me personally, it seems too much like a hack. I think you should not abuse REST so early and should separate serializers by actual end-points and only nest resources if they are nested in the real structure. Because later as your code matures it'll be really difficult to tell where you getting that data you see on display after all.

Comment: How can i combine all of my Serializer to the one `(MovieCastDirectorSerializer)`?

Comment: By defining such serializer in form has_many :movies, has_many :casts, has_many :directors.

Comment: Btw, things like `through:` has no meaning on AMS level. It's just being told to take collection into serialization, no matter where it being assigned from.

Comment: Still not working i got an error `read_attribute_for_serialization`

Comment: That's because my answer was actually not so right in terms of the solution. Your initial code not working because of AMS unable to find a suitable serializer for that and just use AMS on nested objects. But generally AMS only serializes ActiveModel classes so solution is to create virtual class for your three element collection and `include ActiveModel::Model` into that.

Comment: As your answer i should make 2 request and return the data separately right?

Comment: For your actual structure, I think you need to add all those casts and directors to movie serializer. Because what you doing is just trying to move data collection from AMS into controllers. While it's responsibility of AMS to build needed structure for you.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i planed to do at first but seems like there is still some issues that is why i decided to move to this situation. 
So i made new question for that one on this link
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002720/how-to-render-parent-data-of-nested-object-via-active-model-serializers-for-rail`