# How to render parent data of nested object via Active model serializers for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am working on Rails 5 api only app.

So this is my model serializer

```
class MovieSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id ,:name,:release_year,:story,:in_theater,:poster,:score,:user_count

  belongs_to :age_rating
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :categories
  has_many :movie_celebrities

end

class MovieCelebritySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,:vacancy,:title

  belongs_to :celebrity

end

class CelebritySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name

  has_many :movie_celebrities

end
```

My controller

```
class Api::V1::MoviesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /v1/movies/:id
  def show

    movie = Movie.find_by(id: params[:id])

    render json: movie

  end

end
```

So this is what i got

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "0 The Doors of Perception",
  "release_year": 2007,
  "story": "Non doloribus qui et eum impedit. Rerum mollitia debitis sit nesciunt. Vero autem quae sit aliquid rerum ex fugit. Eligendi assumenda et eos. Blanditiis hic ut. Commodi quo sunt voluptatem quasi.",
  "in_theater": false,
  "poster": "'http://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/15399e7a7b11a8c2ef28511107c90c6f.jpg',",
  "score": 0,
  "user_count": 6950,
  "age_rating": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "PG"
  },
  "company": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Gislason, Jacobs and Graham"
  },
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Biography"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Mystery"
    }
  ],
  "movie_celebrities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "vacancy": "director",
      "title": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "vacancy": "cast",
      "title": "Pro x"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "vacancy": "cast",
      "title": "Magneto"
    }
  ]
}
```

By the problem is i need a celebrity data inside each `movie_celebrities` object like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "vacancy": "director",
    "title": "",
    "celebrity": {
      "id": 17,
      "first_name": "Jannie",
      "last_name": "Stiedemann"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "vacancy": "cast",
    "title": "Pro x",
    "celebrity": {
      "id": 56,
      "first_name": "Diego",
      "last_name": "Hickle"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "vacancy": "cast",
    "title": "Magneto",
    "celebrity": {
      "id": 23,
      "first_name": "Myrtie",
      "last_name": "Lebsack"
    }
  }
]
```

So how can i make this situation working?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `render json: @movie, includes: { movie_celebrities: [:celebrity] }`. Its not possible to specify nested associations in the serializer afaik but there is a feature request for it.

Comment: 1st of all, what version of "Serializer" do you use ? Also, try to rename `has_one :celebrity or has_many :celebrities` from `MovieCelebritySerializer `, also remove `has_many :movie_celebrities` from `CelebritySerializer `. Now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `ActiveModelSerializers.config.default_includes = '**'` to `config/initializers/active_model_serializers.rb`. See documentation [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/configuration_options.md#default_includes). Or [set](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md#included) `included` for render right way in case you prefer more granular control.